# Prevent child element's event from bubbling up to it's parent in MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, event-bubbling

I have a `ComboBoxItem` with a child button and I would like to prevent the `ComboBox` from dropping up (collapsing) when that button is clicked. Apparently it seems that the button is bubbling up the click event to the `ComboBoxItem`, causing the drop down to collapse.

```
<ComboBox DropDownOpened="OnWindowsDropDownOpened">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
            <s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
            <s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.HighlightWindow, ElementName=Windows}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" MouseDown="Button_MouseDown" Click="Button_Click">
                            <md:PackIcon Kind="Target" />
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
        </s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxItemStyle}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Valid}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

As we can see, I tried both `MouseDown` and `Click`, handling the event, as follows:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

How do I do that? Also, is it possible to use MVVM code only (XAML-based code, no C#)?

[Here's a screenshot of the ComboBox open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Yza.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you have not tested yet `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and do it by the `ComboBox`. Or you can take another `Preview*` event.

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = sender is Button;
}

<ComboBox DropDownOpened="OnWindowsDropDownOpened" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

Comment: Using `Preview*` events does stop the `ComboBox` from dropping up, but it also does stop the bound `Command` (not fired). Is it possible to have both behaviour working (without moving the Command code to `Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`)? Something like: <Button ChainEvents="False"/>

Comment: You can call `(sender as Button).Command.Execute(null);` in the event handler.

Comment: `(sender as Button).Command.Execute(null);` is trully a nice workaround. Is it possible to do it all with a single button property, as mentioned above? Eg.: `<Button ChainEvents="False"/>`

Comment: I would say no. You could try to put the event handler with command execution to the behavior and use/reuse it in XAML.

Comment: You can also listen for `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` in `ComboBox`, not in `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, elements are selected based on their behavior, not their visual appearance.
The behavior of the ComboBox (including) is to collapse when an item is selected.
If you do not need this, but need an explicit, separate action from the user to collapse the list, then use another element or a combination of them.

In my opinion, the Expander with a nested ListBox will be the most convenient for your task.